# Latitude and Longitude doesn't show on Android Real Device

Tags: android

I watch this tutorial from youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-n6p6RxSS8, when I run the program on the emulator w/ ddms for testing the latitude and longitude it seems to be ok, but when I ran the program on real android device the latitude and longitude doesn't show in the textview
this is the java code:

```
package com.example.mgeolocation;
......
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView textLat;
TextView textLong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
    textLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLong);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new myLocationListener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
}
    private class myLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(location != null){
                double pLong = location.getLongitude();
                double pLat = location.getLatitude();
                textLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
                textLong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + pLat + "\nLong: " + pLong, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
  }
```

and this is the xml file

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Latitude" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Longitude" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLong"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you debug it, is the 'location' null?

Comment: I assume you have GPS enabled and you're outdoors with a view of the sky?

Comment: even I use the toast view, the location doesnt show